# Linking library(dylib) to a compiled ipa

Tags: dylib, ipa, install-name-tool

I have a compiled ipa and a .dylib file. Using install_name_tool I am able to change the libraries present in the ipa file binary. Is there any command which is used to add a library to the ipa. To be more specific i want to add a LC_LOAD_DYLIB command in the Mach-O Binary file of the ipa.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the Mach-o binary to do that. This needs some programming :P Look at mach_inject for more hints.

Comment: I looked into mach_inject. But I could not find a proper sample or tutorial. Can you suggest any documentation?

Comment: Just read the code. You'll need to modify it to play nice with ARM binaries.